# Monte Carlo Error for Minimum Variance Hedge Simulation

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

So I was running a monte carlo simulation for two assets and a portfolio consisting of 1 quantity of the first asset and short a fraction x of the second asset to hedge, where the fraction is calculated as the minimum variance hedge ratio as correlation*volatility spot/volatility futures. Hence, this portfolio should have the lowest variance. However, when I run a monte carlo simulation (i.e. 5000 runs for 1 step f.e. 1 year), the portfolio with the minimum variance hedge ratio gets beat by other hedge ratios. I suppose that this might be due to the error happening in the simulation and the high input parameters and low correlation (I use volatility of 195% for the spot and 30% for the futures and a correlation of 0.1) Is there a way to correct for this error?

Comment: Gets beat. What do you mean? Higher returns? They may have higher returns with more variance.

Comment: @javierazcoiti I mean the portfolio has a higher variance (since the goal is to minimize the variance) the average return is lower. So even though I'm using the optimal hedge ratio after the simulation there are other hedge ratios which can have lower variance.

Comment: I see, the minimum variance hedge is based in past correlation and variances. Did they changed in the MC?

Comment: @javierazcoiti For the simulation of the returns I input the past correlation and variances as you said to simulate and correlate the returns. From there I then simulated the prices by using i.e. the intial stock price as 60 and then computing S*exp(r) (the mean was set to zero). I suspect that when moving from the normally distributed returns to the log-normal level of the prices the correlations changed (so the correlations for the retunrs do not hold at the price level)

Comment: How are you generating the random movements?

Comment: @javierazcoiti I am using the rand function in excel to generate two uniform series, then using the inverse transformation and cholesky decomposition to generate correlated random numbers. Finally I apply the geometric brownian motion equation i.e. mu + sigma*z, where the z is the random number. This procedure then gives me i.e. 2 series of 4000 returns.

Comment: I suggest to check if the simulated paths follow the same past correlations and variances.